# Theos: Trying to take over UIView _subjectLine from CKContentEntryView in ChatKit

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am trying to take control of the subject line in the Messages App. Right now I am just trying to display text in the Subject field.

The main issue I have is to get the compiler to recognize `_subjectLine` as a valid view. This is what I get if I try and do anything to/with `_subjectLine`:

```
Tweak.xm:8: error: ‘_subjectLine’ was not declared in this scope
```

I don't have any idea how to declare an already existing item to use in a tweak. The standard declarations that I use in Xcode, typically found in a header file, don't seem to work the same.

I've been googling around for about a week now. The most common tutorial or information I found was to do just simple: when method activates – display alert. I can do that, no problem. However, I need to use an already existing object.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that in your case you are trying to use an **instance variable** of the class you are hooking. Modifying the instance variable does not work that way in tweaks. You have to use MSHookIvar to 'hook' an instance variable (aka ivar). Example:

[Tweak.xm/mm]

```
#import <substrate.h> // necessary
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TheClassYouAreHooking : NSObject {
    NSString *_exampleVariable;
}
- (void)doSomething;
@end

NSString *_exampleVariableHooked;

%hook TheClassYouAreHooking
- (void)doSomething 
{
    // 'Hook' the variable

    exampleVariableHooked = MSHookIvar<NSString *>(self, "_exampleVariable");

    // The name of the hooked variable does not need to be the same

    exampleVariableHooked = @"Hello World";

    // You can do ANYTHING with the object Eg. [exampleVariableHooked release];

}
%end
```

MSHookIvar can also hook stuff like BOOLs and floats etc.

```
exampleVariableHooked = MSHookIvar<BOOL>(self, "_someBOOL");
```

Its declared in substrate.h so you need to import that otherwise you will not be able to compile your tweak. Also as a bonus tip, I'm just reminding you that you have to put the identifier of the app/framework you're hooking in your tweakname.plist.

So after you 'hook' the variable you can change it to suit your needs. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Objective-C runtime functions to access the instance variable, like so:

```
UIView *subjectLine;
object_getInstanceVariable(self, "_subjectLine", (void **)&subjectLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ChatKit, but took a quick peek.
You can't access _subjectLine because it's an ivar.  You should just access

```
id subject = [myCKContentEntryView subject]; // should return a CKTextContentView
NSAssert([subject isKindOfClass:[CKTextContentView class]], @"ack");
CKTextContentView * myTextContentView = subject;
```

The CKTextContentView has a setText method, but no idea what it's expecting since the parameter is id.  Might be a view (UILabel?) or might take a string.  You might try:

```
[myTextContentView setText:@"Hello World, w/ jimmies!"];
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KVC. Example:
[object valueForKey:@"whatever"];

It works anywhere, and is cleaner than using the Objective C runtime methods, or Mobile Substrate.

Comment: But a class can overwrite the KVC methods and render it useless/unusable.